# Textarea not shown in Django form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm new to Django

In my homepage, I want to give 2 choices to users: to upload photos to a new album, or to an existing one.

The problem is one of the forms is initially not shown in the HTML,I can only see its submit button. But when I click on the submit button, then the form appears, along with the 'This field is required' warnings.

For this I have created 2 forms in **forms.py**

```
class AlbumForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('title', 'description',)


class dropDownForm(forms.Form):
    Albums = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.filter(user__id=1))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(dropDownForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Albums'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(user__id=user.id)
```

AlbumForm is for creating a new album, dropDownForm is for choosing from an existing one.

In views.py I have:

```
def upload_album(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.user.albums.all() is not None:
                albums = request.user.albums.all()
        dropdownAlbum = request.POST.get('Albums')

        if request.method == 'GET':
            album = AlbumForm()
            form = dropDownForm(request.user)
        if ((request.method == 'POST') and ('ExistingAlbum' in request.POST)):
            form = dropDownForm(request.user)
            userID = request.user.id
            curr = UserProfile.objects.filter(id=userID).first()
            curr.currentAlbum = int(dropdownAlbum)
            intAlbum = int(dropdownAlbum)
            curr.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload-media')

        if ((request.method == 'POST') and ('CreateNewAlbum' in request.POST)):
            form2 = AlbumForm(request.POST)
            if form2.is_valid():
                album = form2.save(commit=False)
                album.user = request.user
                album = form2.save()
                created_album_id = Album.objects.filter(title=album).first().id
                userID = request.user.id
                curr = UserProfile.objects.filter(id=userID).first()
                curr.currentAlbum = created_album_id
                curr.save()
                request.user.albums.add(album)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload-media/')

        return render(request, "base.html", locals())
```

and in HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="ExistingAlbum" value="Continue" href="/upload-media/">
</form>

</div>
<div>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="CreateNewAlbum" value="Create New Album">Create</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `form2` does not appear.

The problem is: when you initially request the page it's a `GET` request, therefore only the following part is executed:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    album = AlbumForm()
    form = dropDownForm(request.user)
return render(request, "base.html", locals())
```

Because other `if` branches require `POST`, which is a request verb used when submitting the data, which occurs when you press the `Submit` button.

When you call `locals()` the context is filled with `album` and `form`, but not `form2`, because it's not initialized in local scope in this case. You need to add `form2` initialization to the above part, e.g.:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form2 = AlbumForm()
    form = dropDownForm(request.user)

...

return render(request, "base.html", locals())
```

P.S. Using `locals()` to fill a context is smart, but bad idea - it's insecure, it adds ALL the variables defined in the local scope to the context available in template.

Answer (score 2):

I've just looked up what [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) actually is and that is a *horrible* way of constructing your context data (which is why I'm not surprised I haven't ever heard of it).

Your context data should be a dictionary made up of those values that you **need** in order for your template to render correctly. Therefore you should construct a dictionary that includes the elements that you **need**.

As a starting point that would be.

```
{
    'form': AlbumForm(),
    'form2': dropDownForm(request.user)
}
```